# Unable to store the state of an array inside map - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on reactjs project where i have to store the array value in a local variable that i am parsing form a JSON data . I am successfully able to parse the data using map function , i want to store the result data in a global array , but i am unable to declare state inside map function, how do can i get access to the array which i am retrieving through map. below is my code.

```
 //post data input
  let postData = { Userid: this.props.Userid };

//post data is a method which return's the json array  its a post request
 PostData('UserDetails', postData).then((result) => {
        //storing the data in a variable
         responseJson = result;
        {
              //parsing the json using map
              responseJson.Jiralist.map((rowdata, i) => (
              // i want to store this value in a global array
              console.log("", rowdata.jirakey);
        ))
        }
```

Comment: declare a global array and just `.push()` to it?

Comment: i tried arary.push() ,its  not working inside map.

Comment: it most certinly works inside the map, however using `map` generally is meant to transform an array, so you do not really need to use map, more like forEach or something similar. Then again if you just want to copy an array, `.slice()` works just fine. Post the code where you tried to push so we can see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.
If dont really need to modify the existing array, you can use forEach.
And create a global array and push the new item using spread operator

```
let globalArr = [];

responseJson.Jiralist.forEach((rowdata, i) => ([...globalArr, rowdata.jirakey]))
```

Comment: i was using this.state.gloabalArr and replaced that with  var gloabalArr[] it works fine now , Thank you

Comment: You should be able to do this in state using `setState`.